# Change Column Name

Tags: python, sql-server-2008, t-sql, pyodbc

I have a table called xro_zips_import, which is located on a sql server database. It contain's millions of row of data. I have a column named 'City' and 'CityAliasName' within the table. I need to drop the city column and change the CityAliasName to City. I'm not sure how to use the sp_Rename procedure correctly in Python. This is what I currently have.

```
conn.cursor().execute('ALTER TABLE xro_zips_import DROP COLUMN City')
conn.commit()

conn.cursor().execute("{EXEC sp_RENAME} (?,?,?), ('xro_zips_import.CityAliasName', 'City', 'COLUMN')")
conn.commit()
```

This is the error that I receive after the execution of sp_RENAME

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "Z:\Projects\ZipCodes\ftpUpdate.py", line 274, in 
>       conn.cursor().execute("{EXEC sp_RENAME} (?,?,?), 'xro_zips_import.CityAliasName', 'City', 'COLUMN'") ProgrammingError:
>   ('42000', '[42000] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0]Syntax
>   error, permission violation, or other nonspecific error (0)
>   (SQLExecDirectW)')

Comment: Not sure I understand the problem. (1) does the above not work? If not, how? Do you get an error message? If so, what is it? (2) how often are you dropping and shifting columns that you need to do this from python?

Comment: The Drop Column part of this works fine, but the part where it executes the sp_Rename procedure does not work. This is the error I receive.

conn.cursor().execute("{EXEC sp_RENAME} (?,?,?), 'xro_zips_import.CityAliasName', 'City', 'COLUMN'")
ProgrammingError: ('42000', '[42000] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0]Syntax error, permission violation, or other nonspecific error (0) (SQLExecDirectW)')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up figuring it out. For anyone else that ever runs into this the syntax for sp_rename looks like this.

```
conn.cursor().execute("{call sp_rename(?,?,?)}",('xro_zips_import.CityAliasName', 'City', 'COLUMN'))
conn.commit()
```